# GPG key issue qTox repository

Tags: repository, gnupg, tox

I have noticed that after installing [qTox](https://wiki.tox.im/QTox) and its repository, that when running the commands (and it's either at the end of the first one, or at the beginning of the second one, sorry, but I cannot tell, and it does not happen every time I run them):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That part of the output is this:

```
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.tox.im_dists_nightly_Release.gpg is not what the server reported 473 168
```

I used the following shell script provided [here](https://wiki.tox.im/Binaries#Linux) to add the repository and the GPG key:

```
#remove old key
sudo apt-key del 0C2E03A0

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://repo.tox.im/ nightly main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list'
wget -qO - https://repo.tox.im/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update -qq
echo "Tox Repository Installed."
echo "You can now install utox, qtox, toxic, ratox and tox-bootstrapd"
```

So what does this error message mean? And do I need to do anything about it?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: Had the same problem after deleting the apt lists with `rm -rf /var/apt/lists/* & apt-get clean all`. It went away after rerunning the installation script you also mentioned and running `apt-get update` several times (not only once, but maybe 3x or so). Not sure if this is kind of a Heisenbug and just comes and goes occasionally though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not run a test on 15.04 yet. But, it sounds like something went wrong with the adding of the `ppa`. Could you try and remove everything (q)tox related. Add the ppa again, install `qtox`, and run `update`. If that fixes things, great. I will also test the tox repo on Ubuntu 15.04 later on.

Here is how to remove anything tox related:

**Terminal**

First remove the ppa:

- `sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb https://repo.tox.im/ nightly main"`

Then purge `qtox`:

- `sudo apt-get purge qtox`

Remove/clean/configure left over files

- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

**GUI**

- Go to the dash, search for `Software & Updates`, open it
- Click on the Authentication tab, Remove the `TOX RELENG...` key
- Got to `Other Software` tab, remove the `https://repo.tox.im/`
- Click close it will then ask you to reload,do that.
- and then - in the terminal - run `sudo apt-get purge qtox` also others that you may have installed.
- Clean stuff up with: `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Now, you can try installing Tox again!

Comment: I have not added their PPA before, and when I did recently add it I ran the command to delete the old key (just in case) anyway. I also mentioned this in my question.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I edited my answer.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda added remove information!

Comment: It's a bit long to do it all mostly in the GUI, is there not a Terminal version for all this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda sorry, I didn't know you preferred terminal better.  `ppa-purge` Will do the trick. Install like so: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`. And then `ppa-purge` the ppa.

Comment: Had a similar issue on 15.04. You may want to view my [comment below the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/625001/gpg-key-issue-qtox-repository#comment887382_625001). Maybe it helps you finding out something.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda added terminal commands